# Angular 14: find duplicate image file

Tags: javascript, angular

We have an angular Application where customers can upload photos. Sometime they upload duplicate photos. We have a solution to check if the photo names are same. But we are looking for a way to check the exact content of the photo. Ex: 2 same photos with different names. and we want to just keep one. Is there any Angular/javascript lib available for this or any other suggestion? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the image content has always the same base64 string even if the file name is different. If it is about the exact same Image uploaded twice then:

You could just try to compare the base64 strings of the two images in your method something like:

```
compareImages(image1: string, image2: string): boolean {
    return image1 == image2;
}
```